# Prism: View is not updated after setting value in ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I was unable to bind the values to View from the ViewModel, I can see the values are setting (ServiceList)

Here are the Xaml

XAML:

```
<Label
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    FontFamily="{StaticResource BoldFont}"
                    FontSize="{StaticResource NormalFontSize}"
                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    Text="{Binding Heading, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

PageViewModel:

```
    private string _Heading;
        public string Heading
        {
            get { return _Heading; }
            set { _Heading = value; SetProperty(ref _Heading, value); }
        }

async void LoadData(Service service)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if (App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("user_id"))
                data.Add("user_id", App.Current.Properties["user_id"].ToString());
            data.Add("subcategory", service.id.ToString());
            data.Add("city", "ABC");
            UserResponse = await HomeService.GetServices(data);
            if (UserResponse.status == 200)
            {
                Heading = "529 Interior Decorators in Las Vegas";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `SetProperty` only raises `PropertyChanged` if the value actually changes. By setting it beforehand, you prevent that, and the view cannot know that it should update.

You want to write:

```
public string Heading
{
    get { return _Heading; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _Heading, value); }
}
```

Note the missing `_Heading = value;`